# virsh shows only run VMs

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ovirt

I'm a newbie in Ovirt and I can't get list all VMs (domains) by virsh tool. I run

- virsh -c qemu:///system list --all
- virsh list --all

But virsh always returned only VMs in a running state. There are not one is shutdowned. I can see a lot of VMs by GUI of Ovirt Open virtualization manager (OVM) and in file system (/var/lib/libvirt/qemu). If I run one by Ovirt OVM it's showed by virsh then.

How can I see all VMs by virsh?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you can't. VMs definitions are stored in the oVirt PostgreSQL database.

You have to query the oVirt engine for such information, instead.